# access как синоним для ms-access

Tags: предложение, метки, синонимы-меток

Сделайте, пожалуйста, [access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) синонимом [ms-access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access).

Comment: Обоснуйте пожалуйста. И кстати, далеко не все вопросы с меткой access про ms-access.

Comment: Или [tag:access] пусть будет синонимом для [tag:доступ]?

Comment: Кстати вопросов не про [tag:ms-access] по метке [tag:access] намного меньше, чем про [tag:доступ] или что-то такое.

Comment: ИМХО "доступ" лишняя метка, т.к. она сама по себе ничего не значит, в отрыве от других меток.

Answer (score 9):

### Не надо

Далеко не все вопросы с меткой [access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) про [ms-access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access).

Надо просматривать вопросы индивидуально.

Я бы скорее предложил вообще убрать метки [доступ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf) и [access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) (заменив на [ms-access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access), где уместно). Т.к. они сами по себе ничего не значат, в отрыве от других меток. И только после этого, возможно, сделать синоним [access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) => [ms-access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access).

Comment: А чего сначала нельзя сделать синонимом, если по метке [tag:ms-access] всего лишь 40 вопросов?

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov количество роли не играет. Все равно сначала надо убедится что обе метки используются взаимозаменяемо - а это сейчас не так.

Comment: Без синонима метку по-любому создадут снова...

Comment: @Kromster После удаления [tag:доступ] и [tag:access] синонимизируем [tag:access] и [tag:ms-access] или нет? А то меня слово "возможно" смущает.

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov под словом "возможно", я имею ввиду, что будет создана новая тема на Мете и по ней посмотрим какое будет решение. Может быть, кто-то аргументирует, по итогам проверки всех вопросов с меткой "access", что синонимизировать не надо.