# Объединить метки [access] и [ms-access]

Tags: предложение, синонимы-меток

Есть метка [ms-access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access) с описанием, посвященная БД от Micosoft. И есть метка [access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) без описания, но в первом приближении большинство вопросов так же относят к БД от MS.

Предлагаю следующее:

1. Заменить метку [access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) на более подходящую в тех вопросах, где речь **не** о MS Access. Много где такой меткой может стать [доступ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf) (пока без описания).
2. Сделать [access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) синонимом для [ms-access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ms-access).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [access как синоним для ms-access](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4630/access-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%bc-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-ms-access)

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov связаны, но но дубликаты. Мое предложение больше похоже на ответ Kromster, чем на Ваш вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

А может наоборот, сделать [access](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access) синонимом для [доступ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%be%d1%81%d1%82%d1%83%d0%bf)?

В таком случае, если пользователь напишет в поле тегов `access`, то увидит оба варианта и с лёгкостью выберет правильный.

Comment: Можно и так, но в этом случае придётся править больше вопросов, имхо.

Comment: @alexolut, мне кажется, польза от видимости обеих меток больше, как считаешь?

Comment: Не уверен, что тут будет какая-то реальная польза. Метка [tag:ms-access] создана 01-08-2015, но после этого всё равно появилось [приличное кол-во вопросов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Baccess%5D+created%3A01-08-2015..+is%3Aq+%D0%B1%D0%B4) по БД Access с меткой [tag:access].